# Are option_ids for flags guaranteed to not change?

Tags: support, flags, api

When given an integer as `option_id`, the API path [/answers/{id}/flags/add](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-answer-flag) raises the flag corresponding to `option_id` on a specific answer (same goes for [its counterpart for questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question-flag)). Are these `option_id`s guaranteed to refer to one specific flag for eternity?

For example, does the `option_id` 46534 *always* refer to the spam flag [as defined in the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/flag-option)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, no they are not guaranteed to be the same.  And like badges, the id's are not consistent across sites.
The [docs say as much](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-answer-flag):

> The available flag_options on a answer are not constant, and must be fetched from /answers/{id}/flag/options.

And [this](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/flag-option):

> An application should not assume that... particular option_ids are stable.

EXCEPT:  It may be that the two most egregious flags (*Spam* and *Rude/Abusive*) ARE consistent.  Also, the generic flags *might* be consistent for sites in English.

I picked 3 sites ([*Stack Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/), [*Japanese Stack Overflow*](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/), and [*Sitecore*](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/)).  Choosing (A) the oldest site, (B) a non English site, (C) the newest site.
This kind of choice seems to produce the widest variation in badge ID's, and I posit that the same might be true for flag options.

Here are the results for *question* flags:

```
                                  ID in           ID in           ID in
Flag reason          Flag Class   Stack Overflow  Japanese SO     Sitecore SE
------------------   -----------  --------------  --------------  -----------
Spam                 Auto mdrtng      46534           46534           46534
Rude or Abusive      Auto mdrtng       7852            7852            7852
Duplicate            Specific        varies          varies          varies
Off-Topic            Specific        varies          varies          varies
Migration            Specific        varies          varies          varies
Unclear what asking  Generic          44684           16055           44684
Too broad            Generic           8175           29650            8175
Opinion-based        Generic           1529           62000            1529
Vey low quality      Generic          36772           36772           36772
Problem not listed‡  Generic          22992           34976           22992
```

‡ Value not constant, often shows as 34976 on English sites.

Based on that, I'd say it's safe to assume that the 2 "critical" flags will probably not change, but everything else is either only semi-fixed or completely fluid.

---

Also note that the spam and abuse flag ID's are the same for *answer* flags (That is: 46534 and 7852), but not *comment* flags.

Comment: do note this sentence in the api doc: *The available flag_options on a answer are not constant, and must be fetched from /answers/{id}/flag/options.*

Comment: @rene yes, but that's probably just a CYA due to the unpredictability of the close-reason flags.  In practice, I've yet to find a site that had different spam or abuse constants. ... I haven't checked as many non-close flags, but so far they  only seem to differ on non-English sites.